# Allow all numbers and an optional letter x (case-insenstive) at the end

Tags: javascript, regex

So this is what I have:

```
is_allowed = /^\d+$/.test(my_number)

// variables below should be allowed
my_number = 93420342
my_number = '94354243X'
my_number = '4234x'

// these variables would fail
my_number = 'x'
my_number = '8234a9f'
my_number = 'sadfdX'
my_number = ''
```

Not sure how to include the case-insensitive x at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/^\d+X?$/i`

The `i` flag makes the expression case-insensitive.

Answer (score 5):

How about this regex:

```
^[0-9]+[xX]?$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\d+[xX]?$/g
```

or

```
/^\d+[xX]{0,1}$/g
```